# What is happening in this closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function makeMultiplier(x){
        return function(y) {
            return x * y;
    }
}

var by10 = makeMultiplier(10);
console.log(by10(7));
```

How is it possible to pass in two parameters when make multiplier only accepts one? I'm unsure as to how this syntax is working.

Comment: Where does anything "pass in two parameters"??

Comment: @Pointy: I assume he's talking about how you can call the result of `makeMultiplier()`.

Comment: ^ Correct. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with [tag:jquery]!!!

Comment: Ah my apologies! Included that tag by accident.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain this Javascript closure example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23915510/1048572) or [Returning functions in javascript, understanding scope & closures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8487768/1048572)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How is it possible to pass in two parameters when make multiplier only accepts one?

Because `makeMultiplier()` returns a function.

---

```
function makeMultiplier(x){
    return function(y) {
        return x * y;
    }
}

var by10 = makeMultiplier(10); // by10 is now function (y) { return x * y }, with x bound to 10.
console.log(by10(7)); // So now we can call it like a function.
```

I've coincidentally answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608234/what-does-the-syntax-somefunctionabcd-mean/24608296#24608296) as well today about functions returning functions. It might help.